# Why ConcurrentHashMap read performance is better than HashMap in concurrent environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

In the concurrent environment, and only get object from map, no put. The `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`, Whose performance is better in jdk 1.6.

In my limited experience with these two map, `ConcurrentHashMap` consists of segments. And when get an object from it, it needs at least two locate action. First is to find the correct `segment` and next is to find the correct `table`  while `HashMap` only needs locate once. Further more, in my opinion when we just get object from map, there is no race of lock. So I think in jdk 1.6, there is no doubt that `HashMap` will performance better than  `ConcurrentHashMap` in concurrent environment when just get object from it.

But unfortunately, The test result doesn't support my argument.

Here is my test code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        final Map<Integer, Integer> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        init(hashMap);
        init(concurrentHashMap);
        final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(100);
        long start1 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int count = 0; count < 10000; count++) {
                        hashMap.get(random.nextInt(100));
                    }
                    latch1.countDown();
                }
            }).start();
        }
        latch1.await();
        long end1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("hashMap : " + (end1 - start1));


        final CountDownLatch count2 = new CountDownLatch(100);
        long start2 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int count = 0; count < 10000; count++) {
                        concurrentHashMap.get(random.nextInt(100));
                    }
                    count2.countDown();
                }
            }).start();
        }
        count2.await();
        long end2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("concurrentHashMap : " + (end2 - start2));

    }

    private static void init(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            map.put(i, i);
        }
    }
```

The last three outputs are:

```
hashMap : 78448168
concurrentHashMap : 68820282

hashMap : 87819463
concurrentHashMap : 76098734

hashMap : 87901572
concurrentHashMap : 71385562
```

Then I test the performance in single thread environment.(Repeat random get object from map 10000 times.)

Here is my test result.

[image]

The average time of `HashMap` is 4982047 ns while `ConcurrentHashMap` is 3150367 ns.

The result indicates that `ConcurrentHashMap` performance better than `HashMap` even in single thread environment.

I'm really confused.Is there something that I understand wrong? Or just my test code isn't rigorous?

Comment: Your test code is wrong. `HashMap` being simpler is faster, but that only works with immutable maps so it's not exactly a huge issue.

Comment: If your map doesn't *require* synchronization of any kind, then using `HashMap` is fine.  It will be faster.  `ConcurrentHashMap` is for cases where you *do* need to synchronize (for correctness in a multi-thread application).